# How to print 3D array in same line?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code

```
def main():
x=eval(input())
y=eval(input())
z=eval(input())
n=eval(input())
s=[]
for i in range(0,x+1):
    for j in range(0,y+1):
        for k in range(0,z+1):
            if (i+j+k)!=n:
                print([i,j,k],end='')                
main()
```

Expected output is :

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

My ouput is:

```
[0, 0, 0][0, 0, 1][0, 1, 0][1, 0, 0][1, 1, 1]
```

How to get the expected output?

Comment: It would help to make a [mre] since there's a lot of irrelevant code and missing data here.

Comment: BTW, the better way to get an integer input is `int(input(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You are printing elements of list. Create new list, append all elements and then print finished list:

```
def main():
    x=eval(input())
    y=eval(input())
    z=eval(input())
    n=eval(input())
    s=[]
    for i in range(0,x+1):
        for j in range(0,y+1):
            for k in range(0,z+1):
                if (i+j+k)!=n:
                    s.append([i,j,k])
    print(s)
main()
```